# Where to initialize Auth0 lock in a react app

Tags: reactjs, auth0, auth0-lock

I'm implementing `Auth0` `Lock 11` in my react app. The app is also using `Redux` and `react-router-dom`.

I'm trying to follow the documentation [here](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v11/migration-v9-v11) but having trouble getting initializing `Lock` properly. I'm also confused about how to check if a user is authenticated or not. Before I was using `Lock v9` and things seemed more intuitive.

General behavior that I'm trying to implement is this:

- All of the app will be protected except for `Public` component
- If a user tries to access a protected section, I will `Redirect` user to `Public`

Here's what I have so far. This file is where I keep all `Auth0` code:

```
import Auth0Lock from 'auth0-lock';

export default class Auth { 

    lock = new Auth0Lock('my_client_id', 'mydomain.auth0.com', {

            auth: {
                audience: 'https://myapi.com',
                redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
                responseType: 'token id_token',
                params: {
                    scope: 'openid email profile'
                }
            }
        }
    ).on('authenticated', function(authResult) {

        if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
            this.setSession(authResult);
            // use authResult.idTokenPayload for profile information
        }
    });

    setSession(authResult) {

        debugger
    }

    login() {

        this.lock.show()
    }
}
```

So, here are my questions:

1. Where do I initialize `Lock`? In `App.js`?
2. If the user is not authenticated, he gets redirected to `Public` component. How do I access the `login()` function from `Public`? I understand that I can simply reference it in the component but will that not re-initialize `Lock` all over again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred approach for situations like this is to wrap the App component in an AuthWrapper component that provides AuthContext. Something like this:

```js
import Auth from "./Auth"

const AuthContext = React.createContext({})

class AuthWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.auth = new Auth()
  }

  login = () => {
    this.auth.login()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{ login: this.login }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const { login } = useContext(AuthContext)
  return <button onClick={login}>Show Auth</button>
}
```

If this isn't clear let me know.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you first create a component that will have access to all the `Auth0` code and that's where you initialize it. You then wrap this component around `App.js`, correct? You're essentially creating a `Provider`, right?

Comment: @Sam Yep! The `Auth` in my example would ostensibly be the Auth class you shared in your question. The `AuthWrapper` component is really just serving to hold the reference to it for the sake of making it work with React without using the global scope.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense. The only problem I'm having right now is that after entering username and password and getting an `access_token` from `Auth0`, I'm just not hitting the `lock.on('authenticated'...)`

Comment: @Sam I've not implemented Auth0 before, so I'm not familiar with what might be going on there. Might be best to open up a new question focused on that issue if you need help.